# Slowing down a spaceship rapidly

Tags: technology, space, spaceships

So for unrelated reasons, spaceships approach planets after gliding or accelerating throughout the entire trip. Is there a feasible way to slow down the ship rapidly, with minimal handwavium?

Comment: Rapidly - meaning at a rate much higher than 1g? That would mean you have to handwave acceleration/deceleration effects.

Comment: I think you need to provide more info on the variables in play. How fast is the ship moving? Does this ship resemble the structural integrity of say the Space Shuttle? Do said planets have an Earth-like atmosphere? Are these ships meant to stop or slow down just short of the atmosphere? Is this a manned spaceship? What do you mean by "gliding or accelerating throughout the entire trip?"

Comment: Probably whatever mechanism was used to accelerate the spaceship will be used to deccelerate the spaceship.

Comment: If you don't mind pulping any passengers, use reverse gravity-assist...if a suitable planet happens to be available on your trajectory. Quite a thread-the-needle high-speed maneuver; one mistake and you're off on a 10,000 year ellipse.

Comment: Aerobraking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobraking

Comment: What's wrong with turning around half way and accelerating in the opposite direction, the same way you accelerated in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really; not without just crashing it into a planet and destroying it completely.

Any technology capable of safely slowing down a spaceship from interstellar speed will also be equally capable of accelerating it; and will almost certainly be the most convenient method of accelerating it.

This is why ships powered by [ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_thruster) and [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_propulsion_engine) drives, which are capable of producing a small amount of thrust continuously for a long period of time, will typically accelerate for half of the trip, then turn around and slow down for the second half. If you're using [nuclear pulse propulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_pulse_propulsion), then you'll use half of your delta-V (and more than half of your nukes) to accelerate to cruising speed, then spin around at the end and use the rest of your nukes to stop.

It's possible that you might be able to brake using interstellar gas, the radiation pressure from the target star, or the star's stellar wind, but as far as I know, those things are all far too diffuse to be able to slow down an interstellar ship much.